# Convert date yyyy-mm-dd to integer YYYYMM

Tags: sql-server

How can I convert @dateb:

```
SET @dateb = dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()) - 3, 0)
```

that returns `2014-04-04` as date to an integer of `201404`

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

On version 2012 or higher you can use the [`format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/hh213505.aspx) function to get just year and month, then cast it as an int.

On versions prior to 2012 you can do the formatting with the [`convert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) function, then cast as int.

```
declare @dateb datetime
set @dateb = getdate()

select cast(format(@dateb,'yyyyMM') as int) --2012 or higher
select cast(convert(varchar(6),@dateb,112) as int) -- all versions
```

Comment: [I would avoid `FORMAT()`, generally](http://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but). YMMV.

Answer (score 19):

Perhaps a bit tidier:

```
SELECT YEAR(@dateb)*100 + MONTH(@dateb);
```

Comment: I agree with this wholeheartedly. You have a date, which has integer subfields; you want an integer. Why on earth do any string processing?

Answer (score -1):

Could this do the trick for you?

```
set @dateb = cast(convert(varchar, dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()) - 3, 0), 112) as int)
```

Ah sorry, I forgot, you'll need a substring too.
So it's:

```
select cast(substring(convert(varchar, dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()) - 3, 0), 112), 0, 7) as int)
```

Comment: Please [don't use varchar without specifying the length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length).

Answer (score -1):

Another method:

```
DECLARE @PeriodToCalculate_DATE [DATE] ='2016-02-29'

SELECT 
   CAST(DATEPART(YYYY,@PeriodToCalculate_DATE) AS [CHAR](4))
       + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(M,@PeriodToCalculate_DATE) AS [VARCHAR](2)),2)  
       + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(D,@PeriodToCalculate_DATE) AS [VARCHAR](2)),2);
```

Gives: 20160229